# Equation for the velocity of a roller coaster at every point

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been issued a task to create a roller coaster comprised of a piecewise function. In my research I have come across the an equation to calculate the final velocity of the cart found at https://www.teachengineering.org/activities/view/ind-1996-frictional-roller-coaster-design-project-calculus.

\begin{equation}
v_f^2= v_i^2-2g\big(f(x_f)-f(x_i)\big)-\frac{4}{7}g \mid  f(x_f)-f(x_i)\mid
\end{equation}
My questions: Is anyone familiar with this equation or the associated differential equation? How is it derived? How do I find a friction-less case? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Ak19 it is the same link?

Comment: Oops, sorry. This [one](https://www.teachengineering.org/lessons/view/ind-1996-friction-force-along-curved-path-ap-calculus)

Comment: @Ak19 How would you construct a friction-less equation?

Comment: I think you may ask this in Physics SE.